# using crashplan to backup multiple machines to crashplan-central using a single hub machine

Tags: online-backup, backup, crashplan, crashplan-central

I am playing around with CrashPlan for the last few days, and i am still trying to get the hang of it. one thing i have noticed is that upload to CrashPlan Central from my work laptop is only sending data at a max of 400kb/s... My home laptop is about 200kb/s max... but my dedicated server in Germany is uploading at about 8mb/s, and thats limited in the control pannel...  Also, backing up data from the work and home laptops are running at closer to 1-3mb/s each... (I might be able to get that faster if i do an initial backup to a folder and then upload that to the server using FTP or SFTP or something else, but thats out of scope for the question).

And now the question: If i backup my machines (more coming) to the dedicated server, they go to a particular folder (C:\ProgramData\CrashPlan\backupArchives in my case). Is it a good idea to set that folder to be backed up by crashplan on that server to CrashPlan Central? In other words, is it a good idea to use a single box as a "hub" to CrashPlan Central?

Comment: Stupid Rep system on SuperUser is causing me to put this as a comment... Looks like this is putting a kibosh on the whole idea: http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/articles/admin_excludes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CrashPlan doesn't backup CrashPlan Archives, so you can't select them.
If a friend backup's to your computer and you to crashplan-central, his archives on your computer won't be uploaded.

It could be, though, that the enterprise and business versions have a feature that makes this possible. Best write to their support.